# SQL statement with multiple condition check

Tags: sql

I have two tables structured as below:

Table customers:

[image]

Table orders:

[image]

Two tables are joined on customers.CUST_ID_NUM = orders.CUST_ID_NUM, so it is like:

```
select * from customers
join orders
on customers.cust_id_num=orders.cust_id_num;
```

After joining two tables 3 cases could happen:

1. If more than one records are present for one cust_id_num, then remove the record on condition: orders.tran_id = orders.alt_id
2. If we still get more than one record for that cust_id_num, then keep the record with the latest orders.tran_ts
3. if we only have one record for one cust_id_num, then keep it.

in short, in the final result. each cust_id_num should only appear once.

the result of joining is:

[image]

so according to the above logic, row 1 would be removed first, because it has same tran_id and alt_id. Then row 2 would be removed also, because it does not have the latest tran_ts. So, only last two rows will be kept in the final table.

Another example would be:

[image]

in this case, again, row 1 would be removed, as it does not have the latest tran_ts. and only last rows will be kept.

I am not very sure how this kind of logic can be achieved with SQL, if anyone can give a clue or any help, that would be great and appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `row_number` to order the results in the manner you wanted and then chose the first row (desc).

```
select cust_id_num  
      ,tran_ts  
      ,tran_id  
      ,alt_id   
      ,name
from  (  
       select *
              ,row_number() over(partition by cust_id_num order by case tran_id when alt_id then 0 else 1 end desc, tran_ts desc) as rn
       from    orders join customers using(cust_id_num)
       ) t
where  rn = 1
```

| cust_id_num | tran_ts | tran_id | alt_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 03:00:00.000000 | 123 | 777 | alex |
| 456 | 2022-01-0101:00:00.000000 | 777 | 777 | jane |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IZ-He2HM?hide=4)